# Hidden wire detector, using resistor

Tags: bjt, antenna, electromagnetic, detection

We have on the collector of the first transistor is a resistor at 1000 ohms , could you tell us what function this resistor performs in this place and how to argue that it is at 1000 ohms
[image]

Comment: This looks like homework without any attempt at a solution. Please [edit] your question to show your work so far or the question is likely to be closed. If the schematic is not your own then you need to credit the author or link to the source. Please capitalise and punctuate properly for clarity and ease of reading.

Comment: The circuit of the device is a composite transistor, consisting of three conventional. The result is a sensitive amplifier (with a current transfer gain of more than 100,000), the load of which is the LED.
Any LED has a small resistance. If you connect it directly to the power supply, it will burn out immediately, as the current will be too high.
Thus, we made a choice in the direction of a resistor with a nominal value of 1 kOhm, since if we used a resistor with a value of less than 680 Ohms, it would be more likely that the LED would burn out.
Am i thinking right?

Comment: no, the current in that resistor will be amplified twice (by the next two transistors  and you could get 1000 times more.  but that resistor makes no sense to me. it seems like resistors on the other transistors would be good too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having built numerous multi-stage bipolar amplifiers as a kid, I'd wager this resistor is to limit current.

Those amplifiers, lo those many years ago, would produce a power-line humming or evil-singing/buzzing (from quick rectifier diode turnon) as I brought my hand near the floating input of my breadboard multi-stage audio-band gain-of-100,000X circuit. There was enough gain the ELECTRIC FIELDS were being detected.

Thus very similar to this 3-transistor very-high-Rinput circuit.

Yes, I'd include resistors in all three collectors. Perhaps 1,000/1,000/100 ohms.

===================================

Remember the input lead is floating, your body is the return path for the induced charges as you hold the circuit near the wall, as you watch for a slightly-glowing LED.

Comment: it seems kind of low for that.